# Can't evaluate the limit of the following expression

Tags: calculus, limits

I can't evaluate the limit of the following expression:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{2x + 3}}{3x - 1}
$$
Taking the square root in the numerator is confusing me.

Comment: Divide top and bottom by $x$...

Comment: Note that there is no **equation.**  You are trying to find the limit of the expression.

Comment: Presumably you *know* what the thing is like when $x$ is huge. Like $x\approx 10^{12}$. The top is $\lt 2\times 10^6$, the bottom is $\approx 3\times 10^{12}$, the ratio is real close to $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide the numerator and denominator by $x$, and note that $x = \sqrt {x^2},\;$ since  ($x\to +\infty \implies x>0$).

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt {2x+ 3}}{3x - 1} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{\frac{\sqrt {2x+ 3}}{\sqrt {x^2}}}{\frac{3x - 1}{x}} =\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt {\frac{2}{x} + \frac 3{x^2}}}{3 - \frac 1x} = \dfrac {0}3 = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

First note that for $x > 3$ we have $2x+3 < 3x$ and $3x-1 > 2x$. Hence, we have for $x > 3$, $$0 < \dfrac{(2x+3)^{0.5}}{3x-1} < \dfrac{(3x)^{0.5}}{2x} = \dfrac{\sqrt3}2 \dfrac1x$$
Now conclude what you want.